SQL - unknown column "d.datum" in where clause - trying to calculate between 3 tables
The column exist, but he still gives me this error. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
UPDATE dashboard_19_2 d
SET d.mwst_abs = (
    SELECT SUM(berechneter_mwst)
    FROM (
        SELECT s.ordernumber, (s.invoice_amount / 100) * max_tax_rate AS berechneter_mwst
        FROM s_order s
        JOIN (
            SELECT ordernumber, MAX(tax_rate) AS max_tax_rate
            FROM s_order_details
            WHERE price > 0
            GROUP BY ordernumber
        ) sd ON s.ordernumber = sd.ordernumber
        WHERE DATE(s.ordertime) = d.datum
        AND s.subshopID = 19
    ) AS mwst_berechnungen
);

I want to calculate a column by calculating the sum of the invoice amount divided by hundred on one table and then multiplicated by the tax rate of another table.

The problem is that d.datum is in the subquery of a subquery, meaning the d alias is not visible there. I would try to get rid of the sum() subquery.

Use UPDATE+JOIN rather than a subquery.

You can use a LATERAL JOIN
UPDATE dashboard_19_2 d
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT SUM(s.invoice_amount / 100) * max_tax_rate AS berechneter_mwst
    FROM s_order s
    JOIN (
        SELECT ordernumber, MAX(tax_rate) AS max_tax_rate
        FROM s_order_details
        WHERE price > 0
        GROUP BY ordernumber
    ) sd ON s.ordernumber = sd.ordernumber
    WHERE DATE(s.ordertime) = d.datum
      AND s.subshopID = 19
) s
SET d.mwst_abs = s.berechneter_mwst;

